# retrofit is not getting the id of JSON object

Tags: android, json, retrofit, isnull

it's getting name, status and login successfully. But it's assigning 0 to u_id (user id)  , which should be 4. Maybe it's getting Id as a string from a Json perhaps?I dunno the correct JSON format for integers.

JSON:

```
{
  "id": "4",
  "name": "nuku",
  "status": "1",
  "login": "sucess"
}
```

POJO:
public class LoginModel {

```
    @Expose
    public static int id;

    @Expose
    public String name;

    @Expose
    private String status;
    @Expose
    private String login;
...}
```

interface:

```
   String url = "http://192.168.10.5/tourist/v1";
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/login")
    void Login(@Field("email") String email,
               @Field("pass") String pass, Callback<LoginModel> cb);
}
```

retrofit function call:

```
RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(RestInterface.url).build();

                    //Creating Rest Services
                    final RestInterface restInterface = adapter.create(RestInterface.class);

                    //Calling method to get check login
                    restInterface.Login(email.getText().toString(), pass.getText().toString(), new Callback<LoginModel>() {
                        @Override
                        public void success(LoginModel model, Response response) {

                            //finish();
                            //startActivity(getIntent());

                            email.setText("");
                            pass.setText("");

                                 int id = model.getUserId();
                            if (model.getStatus().equals("1")) {  //login Success

                                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyLogin.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                                editor.putBoolean("FirstLogin", true);
                                editor.commit();



                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login In SuccessFully"+model.getUserId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                manager.setPreferences(LoginActivity.this, "status", "1");
                                String status=manager.getPreferences(LoginActivity.this,"status");

                                Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);


                                String name = model.getUser_name();
                                i.putExtra("username", name);
                               // String image = p.getPlace_image();
                               // i.putExtra("Thumbnail", image);
                                i.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_USER,"username");
                                startActivity(i);



                              //  String nameStr = email.getText().toString();

                                // i.putExtra("text1", nameStr);
                                //startActivity(i);

                            } else if (model.getStatus().equals("0"))  // login failure
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Invalid UserName/Pass ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                                startActivity(i);

                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                            finish();
                            startActivity(getIntent());
                            String merror = error.getMessage();
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, merror, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Comment: At first glance everything seems alright with the code. Are you sure that's the json you're getting from the API? Can you somehow confirm this?

Comment: @Fred yeah, I copied it straight from postman preview.

Comment: That looks like a String, rather than an Integer. Did you try retreive it as a string and then convert it to an integer?

Comment: @cuoka I dunno how to do that should I cast it to integer in the response function or  in the login model am totally confused

Comment: @cuoka am trying this hope this'll work  LoginModel lm = response.body();
                                int u_id = ((int) lm.getUserId());

Comment: @NukhbaArshad Take a look at my response, see if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either your LoginModel is not correct or the one sending the JSON is not doing it right. Your ID in the JSON is a String, not an Integer (notice the double quotes)

You'll have to change the ID type to String in your LoginModel, but, IMO, a better solution would be receive it as an Integer.

This is an example of a JSON with an Integer in it:

```
{
 "email":"some@email.com",
 "age":25,
 "man":true,
 "password":"123456"
}
```

Comment: @NukhbaArshad Great, please, accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried getting Id as string but retrofit assigned null to it so I just converted my JSON into integer using this echo json_encode($output,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); and It worked!